# <h:commandButton> not working inside <ui:define>

Tags: jsf-2, netbeans-7

I created a facelet template called loginRegisterTemplate.xhtml. When I use it in a template client and I place a  in it, the method in the managed bean is not invoked. Without the template the button is working fine. Why is this happening?

```
    <ui:composition template="resources/css/faceletsTemplates/loginRegisterTemplate.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="top">
            Login Page
        </ui:define>
        <ui:define name="content">
            <div align="center">
                <h:panelGrid columns="3" columnClasses="rightalign,leftalign,leftalign">

                    <h:outputLabel value="Username:" for="userName"/>
                    <h:inputText id="userName" label="Username" required="true" value="#{loginBean.userName}" />
                    <h:message for="userName" />

                    <h:outputLabel value="Password:" for="password"/>
                    <h:inputText id="password" label="Password" required="true" value="#{loginBean.password}" />
                    <h:message for="password" />
                </h:panelGrid><br/>

                <h:button value="Back to Home" outcome="home"/>
                <h:commandButton id="login" value="Login" action="#{loginBean.doLogin}"/>
            </div>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
```

The simple `<h:button>` next to it, on the other side, is working fine.

Here is the body of my template file:

```
<h:body>
    <div id="top">
        <ui:insert name="top">Top</ui:insert>
    </div>
    <div id="content" class="center_content">
        <ui:insert name="content">Content</ui:insert>
    </div>
</h:body>
```

I have looked here: [h:commandLink / h:commandButton is not being invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked/2120183#2120183) but I couldn't find which problem causes that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why is the `h:commandButton` not working?**

Your problem is number 1 in the [answer you have checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked/2120183#2120183).

> UICommand and UIInput components must be placed inside an UIForm
>   component, e.g. `<h:form>`.

**Why is the `h:button` working then ?**

from the [`h:button` docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserverfaces/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/h/button.html):

> Render an HTML "input" element of type "button". The value of the
>   component is rendered as the button text and the outcome of the
>   component is used to determine the target URL which is activated by
>   onclick.

**So ...**

JSF will put your `h:button` `outcome` value in a javascript function that will be executed at an `onclick` event. But it will execute the `action` of the `h:commandButton` on the form submit with the `POST` method, so there should be a form to submit.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really don't know how I missed it, and I was stuck into looking for more complex solutions!